# QEMU emulation error

Tags: windows-7, qemu, emulation

I've downloaded an ISO image I want to emulate (Win7 64 bit) through QEMU, but it returns [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDxZB.jpg). All the tutorials/walkthroughs i've seen were all done on linux, and I've tried to get it to run though batch files in the same directory, but no luck. [Drag and Drop Clip](https://streamable.com/n1obs)